# What am I doing wrong with my list animations?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

Basically, I want to have my unordered list items animate in line by line.
So, initially, this was how the animation got started for one line of text.

```
var spanWidth = $('ul.imagelist span').width();
$('ul.imagelist span').animate( { width: spanWidth }, 3000 );
```

So, for five unordered list to animate one by one I figured I can use setTimeout functions, here is what I have tried so far http://jsfiddle.net/ottster/8ynvymnk/ as you can see in the result windows it appears to disappear slide in and comes back in I'm not sure what's going on. Some assistance and or directions would be appreciated.

Comment: You want them to initially be hidden and to slide in?

Comment: check this modification http://jsfiddle.net/8ynvymnk/3/ You were doing several functions for each iteration, there is no need to select each element through your cicle when you are already going through each one of them.

Comment: Ah nice, and yes would be nice to initially hidden then slide in one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

**JS:**

```
$('ul.imagelist span').each(function(i) {  
  var t = $(this); 
  setTimeout(function() {  
    t.parent(".text").show();
    t.animate( { width: t.width() }, 1000);
  }, (i + 1) * 1000);  
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.text{
  display:none;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mhshimul/ev2t6ndk/2/)